# installing nvidia grpahics driver for cuda computation only

Tags: nvidia, graphics, cuda

I am having screen freeze after nvidia graphics driver installation. Is there a way to restrict the nvidia drivers' use for cuda computation alone (not for the desktopn gui display)? I am trying to use cuda 6.5 (ubuntu 14.04) on a gt 755m graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for this..
http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x
Got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949573/how-to-use-all-cuda-devices-only-for-computation-not-for-display-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! sort of put it on back burner . Will check it out. Thanks !

Comment: Turned out that it was a stupid driver issue.  It now works perfectly with a recent driver